# vtiger customer portal 5.4.0 - Could not connect to server - XML error parsing SOAP payload: Not well-formed

Tags: vtiger

If I try to login in the vtiger customer portal i get the error "Could not connect to server".

I have installed vtiger 5.4.0 and vtiger customer portal 5.4.0.
The machine is a Linux CentOS 6, php version 5.3.3.

In the "vtiger_del\config.inc.php" i have:

```
$PORTAL_URL = 'http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance';
```

In the "\vtiger_del\assistance\PortalConfig.php" i have:

```
$Server_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com";
$Authenticate_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance";
```

When I try to enter in vtiger customer portal with user and pwd I get the "Could not connect to server" error.
I have removed the comment in CustomerAuthenticate.php to view the error; the error is:

### Error Message

```
XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Not well-formed (invalid token)
```

### request

```
POST /vtigerservice.php?service=customerportal HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.6.7 (1.1)
Host: crmdel.domain.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://crmdel.domain.com"
Content-Length: 684

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticate_user xmlns:ns1="http://crmdel.domain.com"><user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">username@gmail.com</user_name><user_password xsi:type="xsd:string">hnz42vtg</user_password><version xsi:type="xsd:string">5.4.0</version></ns1:authenticate_user></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2013 10:57:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.7.2 (1.94)
Content-Length: 2366
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 10:57:57 GMT
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8


Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 3638
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticate_userResponse xmlns:ns1="http://crmdel.domain.com"><return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[1]"><item xsi:type="xsd:"><id xsi:type="xsd:string">125</id><user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">username@gmail.com</user_name><user_password xsi:type="xsd:string">hnz42vtg</user_password><last_login_time  xsi:nil="true"/><support_start_date xsi:type="xsd:string">2013-03-25</support_start_date><support_end_date xsi:type="xsd:string">2014-03-25</support_end_date><sessionid xsi:type="xsd:string">tlhn36ds</sessionid></item></return></ns1:authenticate_userResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### debug

```
soapclient2: call: authenticate_user, Array, http://crmdel.domain.com, http://crmdel.domain.com, , rpc, encoded; endpointType: 
soapclient2: serializing param array for operation authenticate_user
soapclient2: in serialize_val: username@gmail.com, user_name, , , , , encoded
soapclient2: in serialize_val: hnz42vtg, user_password, , , , , encoded
soapclient2: in serialize_val: 5.4.0, version, , , , , encoded
soapclient2: wrapping RPC request with encoded method element
soapclient2: endpoint: http://crmdel.domain.com/vtigerservice.php?service=customerportal, soapAction: http://crmdel.domain.com, namespace: http://crmdel.domain.com, style: rpc, use: encoded
soapclient2: SOAP message length: 684 contents: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticate_user xmlns:ns1="http://crmdel.domain.com"><user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">username@gmail.com</user_name><user_password xsi:type="xsd:string">hnz42vtg</user_password><version xsi:type="xsd:string">5.4.0</version></ns1:authenticate_user></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
soapclient2: transporting via HTTP
soapclient2: sending message, length: 684
soapclient2: transport debug data...
soap_transport_http: scheme = http
soap_transport_http: host = crmdel.domain.com
soap_transport_http: path = /vtigerservice.php
soap_transport_http: query = service=customerportal
soap_transport_http: entered send() with data of length: 684
soap_transport_http: connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme http, host crmdel.domain.com, port 80
soap_transport_http: calling fsockopen with host crmdel.domain.com
soap_transport_http: socket connected
soap_transport_http: wrote data to socket, length = 904
soap_transport_http: read line of 17 bytes: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
soap_transport_http: read line of 37 bytes: Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2013 10:57:57 GMT
soap_transport_http: read line of 16 bytes: Server: Apache
soap_transport_http: read line of 36 bytes: X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.7.2 (1.94)
soap_transport_http: read line of 22 bytes: Content-Length: 2366
soap_transport_http: read line of 32 bytes: Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
soap_transport_http: read line of 40 bytes: Expires: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 10:57:57 GMT
soap_transport_http: read line of 24 bytes: X-Powered-By: PleskLin
soap_transport_http: read line of 23 bytes: Vary: Accept-Encoding
soap_transport_http: read line of 19 bytes: Connection: close
soap_transport_http: read line of 39 bytes: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
soap_transport_http: read line of 2 bytes: 
soap_transport_http: found end of headers after length 307
soap_transport_http: want to read content of length 2366
soap_transport_http: read buffer of 2366 bytes
soap_transport_http: read to EOF
soap_transport_http: read body of length 2366
soap_transport_http: received a total of 2673 bytes of data from server
soap_transport_http: closed socket
soap_transport_http: end of send()

soapclient2: got response, length: 2366 type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
soapclient2: Entering parseResponse() for data of length 2366 and type text/xml; charset=UTF-8
soapclient2: Got response encoding: UTF-8
soapclient2: Use encoding: UTF-8 when creating soap_parser
soapclient2: soap_parser: Entering soap_parser(), length=2366, encoding=UTF-8
soap_parser: XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Not well-formed (invalid token)
soap_parser: XML payload:

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 5681

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in /var/www/.../vtiger_del/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 3638
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticate_userResponse xmlns:ns1="http://crmdel.domain.com"><return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[1]"><item xsi:type="xsd:"><id xsi:type="xsd:string">125</id><user_name xsi:type="xsd:string">username@gmail.com</user_name><user_password xsi:type="xsd:string">hnz42vtg</user_password><last_login_time  xsi:nil="true"/><support_start_date xsi:type="xsd:string">2013-03-25</support_start_date><support_end_date xsi:type="xsd:string">2014-03-25</support_end_date><sessionid xsi:type="xsd:string">tlhn36ds</sessionid></item></return></ns1:authenticate_userResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

soapclient2: Error: XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Someone could tell why?

Comment: have you tried localhost in 5.4 portal config, I mean if apache localhost shows ^some path^/www and vtiger is installed in ^some path^/www/folder1/folder2, customer portal url should be http://localhost/folder1/folder2

Comment: Now I tried this way:

`$PORTAL_URL = 'http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance';`

`$Server_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/crm";
$Authenticate_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance";`

The folders in the server are:
`Vtiger: /var/www/.../vtiger_del/crm
Portal: /var/www/.../vtiger_del/assistance`

but return same error

Comment: what I percieved: your www folder includes vtiger_del/crm for vtiger and vtiger_del/assistance . So config should be like:  $PORTAL_URL = 'http://crmdel.domain.com/vtiger_del/assistance' --- $Server_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/vtiger_del/crm" --- $Authenticate_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/vtiger_del/assistance";  for sure $PORTAL_URL in vtiger config and $Authenticate_Path in customer portal are the same.

Comment: No no. My DNS domain crmdel.domain.com is `/var/www/.../vtiger_del/`. In this folder there are tho folder: `crm` and `assistance`. 
So link vtiger is `crmdel.domain.com/crm/` and portal link is `crmdel.domain.com/assistance/`. 
Then `$PORTAL_URL = 'http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance'; $Server_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/crm"; $Authenticate_Path = "http://crmdel.domain.com/assistance";` Thanks you for the help you're giving me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your installation is meeting correct requirement that vtiger expected, 
It seems the SoapClient Couldn't parse wsdl Correctly because the Warnings that PHP Outputs. So please make the changes in php.ini file, that mentioned in vtiger [wiki](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/System_Requirements#PHP_Configuration)

Please Have a look on this variable : 
*error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable error reporting.
To turn off PHP error reporting you can use the following snippet in config.inc.php:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

You can also turn off php error messages by editing php.ini